# Error in ssis script component Max String Content Length

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, ssis, dynamics-crm-4

hello i have a problem with the ssis script component i try to get the attr document body from table Annotation in **SDK**  and i get the error

"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter [http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:RetrieveResult](http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services%3aRetrieveResult). The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type CRM.Proxy.CrmSdk.Entity. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 428045.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."

public byte[] GetAllAnnotations(Guid attachmentId)
    {

```
    Entity attachment;
    ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet();
    columnSet.Columns = new string[] { "filename", "documentbody", "mimetype" };
    attachment = service.Retrieve("annotation", attachmentId, columnSet);

    MessageBox.Show(attachment["documentbody"].ToString());
    if (attachment == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment["documentbody"].ToString()))
        return null;

    return Convert.FromBase64String(attachment["documentbody"].ToString());

}
```

Comment: Are you using any configuration file in your script.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde   no